# Fill select with array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-select

I have this result from my firebase in a variable :

```
[
    {
        "value": "CHProNd9BGYznrEr0u43",
        "label": "Jean"
    },
    {
        "value": "Huo0mofwJGKx2uEd9467",
        "label": "aaa"
    },
    {
        "value": "IO5w6WstNngCNyKRneYg",
        "label": "African"
    }
]
```

I get this result with this call to firebase :

```
export async function getCoupeurs() {

      let getCoupeurFromFirebase = [];
          const coupeursRef = collection(db, "coupeurs");
          getDocs(coupeursRef).then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
              getCoupeurFromFirebase.push({
              value: doc.id,
              label: doc.data().nom,
              });
          });
        });
    
        return getCoupeurFromFirebase;
    }
```

and i want to fill this select input :

```
<select>
{ 
  coupeurs.map(coupeur => (
    <option key={coupeur.value} value={coupeur.value}>{coupeur.label}</option>
  ))
}
</select>
```

but i have nothing on my screen and no error, can you help me to do this by the best way ?
[updated]
The code on codepen.io , that work so i think the problem is the call for data from database there is a way to tell that i want to wait the result before send the data to my component ?

https://codepen.io/lbain/pen/ENpzBZ

```
<select>
          {
            coupeurs.map(coupeur => (
              <option>{coupeur.label}</option>
            ))
          }
</select>
```

thanks.

Comment: can you please post a [mcve]

Comment: thank that permit me to reliese that the problem can from firebase calling and wating for data

Comment: `coupeurs` will be null when you don't have a response from your firebase server unless you have initialized it with some value.
Nevertheless, your initialization has to be of type `array`.
Next, how are you making the firebase call and are you updating a state? If not, you should update states to cause re-renders.

Comment: @ArjisChakraborty i add the call to firebase part, how tell to react that i want to wait datas before render ?

Comment: We can't do that...you can't wait for renders. You have to set a loader of some kind and use some conditional statements to check if you have data to show otherwise show the loader instead. You can easily do this using `setState` for functional components.

Comment: No i havent found the right wait to achieve it